# Platformer Sprite is inside of a Solid Sprite

Tags: collision-detection, sprites, construct-2

My platformer sprite in Construct 2 works normally aside from it not colliding correctly with platform sprites that are solid, as it goes through them until the platform is not quite halfway up the platformer sprite, and I cannot figure out why.

[image: Black box head on top of a black platform]

[image: Black box head with legs]

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Had to edit collision box polygons, this was not explained in the tutorial I am using.

Comment: Since explanation of this is apparently lacking in current online resources, you can make things easier for the next developer in your shoes by **editing your answer** to explain *how* you edited those collision boxes to fix the problem. What were the steps of that process? This information can help future readers learn more efficiently.